# Add rectangle to Canvas using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

How do i add Rectangle to my View using MVVM?

This is the code for my view.

```
<Grid>
            <Image  x:Name="img"  Source="{Binding ImagePath, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" >
            </Image>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListRectangle, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" >

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent"  x:Name="cnvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=ActualHeight}"
                        LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=LayoutTransform}" >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                    <!--<command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cnvas}" Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />-->
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDownEvente" TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Blue"  Fill="Transparent" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

and this is my View Model

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        public void MouseDownEvente(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (s == null) return;
                canvas = s as Canvas;
                if (canvas == null) return;

                startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

                // Remove the drawn rectanglke if any.
                // At a time only one rectangle should be there
                //if (rectSelectArea != null)
                //    canvas.Children.Remove(rectSelectArea);

                // Initialize the rectangle.
                // Set border color and width
                rectSelectArea = new Rectangle
                {
                    Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                };

                Canvas.SetLeft(rectSelectArea, startPoint.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(rectSelectArea, startPoint.X);
                canvas.Children.Add(rectSelectArea);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

But its throwing an error:

```
Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.
```

So how do i solve this?

I tried searching the same problem with mine. And used the solution that worked to them. But the error still persist. Can someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: Draw a selection rectangle on top of the ItemsControl. Having it in the ItemsPanel won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.

This means that you cannot use `Canvas.Children.Add` when you use `Canvas` as an `ItemsPanel` for an `ItemsControl`. You should add items on where the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property is bound to (in your case `ListRectangle`).

Comment: So that's the proper way to update the canvas? thank you

Comment: That's the proper way if you use Canvas as an ItemsPanelTemplate of an ItemsControl. If you use Canvas as it is, then you can use its Children.Add.